# How to find new line characyter

Tags: java

I want to know how can i read the contents of a file, character by character?

I tried this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(newFileReader("C:\\saml.txt")));

while(sc.hasNext())
{
String s=sc.next();
char x[]=s.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
if(x[i]=='\n')
System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println(x[i];
}
```

I want to give input in file as:
"pure
world
it
is"

I want the output
"pure
hello
world
hello
it
hello
is
hello"

Comment: it looks like you'Re not looking for  a newline `\n`, but for a space `\s`.

Comment: If you need just detect a newline character, then I'd recommend you to simply read file line-by-line, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java).

Comment: provide what error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Compare the string read against [`System#lineSeparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29). If you use Java 6 or prior, use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`:

   ```
   String s = sc.next();
   if (System.lineSeparator().equals(s)) {
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Use `Scanner#nextLine` that will return a String until it finds a line separator character(s) (it will consume the line separator character(s) for you and remove it), then split the string by empty spaces and work with every string between spaces.

   ```
   String s = sc.nextLine();
   String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
   for (String word : words) {
       //...
   }
   ```

Note that in any of these cases you don't need to evaluate each character in the `String`.

Comment: Hey, the second code is printing out for space too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `Scanner.nextLine` and either using `String.join`(java 8+) or going for the manual method:

Without a trailing "hello":

```
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            String[] words = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            String sentence = words[0];
            for(int i = 0; ++i < words.length;)
                sentence += " hello " + words[i];
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
```

With a trailing "hello":

```
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            for(String w : sc.nextLine().split(System.getProperty("line.separator")))
                System.out.print(w + " hello ");
            System.out.println();
        }
```